# .htaccess HTTPS and remove index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have found several answers to this question but slightly different, the funny thing is that it didn't work for me.

My goal is to rewrite any url to HTTPS and remove the index.php

Basically what I want is to merge the following two htaccess files but I am somewhat new to the htaccess syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If needed add 'www'
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```